# Writing a great, reusable "to_s" method for better debugging

Tags: ruby, object

I have a couple of objects I would like to `puts` quite often for debugging.
[Objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) default `to_s` method is not that great for that purpose. In general I feel like you would want to *look into* the instance (so the most interesting part are the instance variables) so I came up with this:

```
class DebugObject
    def initialize(args)
      raise ArgumentError unless args.is_a? Hash
      args.each { |k,v| instance_variable_set "@#{k}".to_sym,v } 
    end

    def to_s
      str = "#{self.class}:\n"
      instance_variables.each do |var|
        str += " %s: %s" % [var, instance_variable_get(var)]
      end
      str
    end
end

class User < DebugObject
  attrs = [:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :postal_code, :city]
  attrs.each { |attr| attr_accessor attr }
end

class CreditCard < DebugObject
  attrs = [:holder, :number, :cardinalidity, :cvc, :error_code, :error_message]
  attrs.each { |attr| attr_accessor attr }
end
```

which when used with puts gives me:

```
User:
 @first_name: Peter @last_name: Parker @street: Street number @postal_code: 9020
 @city: New york @email: peter@parker.com

CreditCard:
  @holder: Martin @number: 00000 @cardinalidity: 09/10 @cvc: 123
  @error_code: 00 @error_message: No eroro :)
```

I was wondering if you have any tips and tricks for writing a great, reusable `to_s` method thats useful while debugging?

Comment: since there’s no multiple inheritance in Ruby, your classes probably shouldn’t *inherit from* a `DebugObject` class, but rather `include` a **module** `DebugObject`.

Comment: @fanaugen thats a great point, thanks

Comment: Agree about using modules. But if all you want is instance variables, then `inspect` may fit you. I played in IRB a little and it seems like  for user-defined classes `.inspect` shows instance variables, unlike `.to_s`: https://gist.github.com/NIA/4959907

Comment: @NIA yeah I pretty much just replicated `inspect` but the thing is I want to "save" typing `.inspect` :) and when I wrap `inspect` in `to_s` I get a stack level too deep error?

Comment: @sytycs, well, stack overflow is because in some cases `.inspect` actually simply calls `.to_s` so you will get infinite recursion. You can meditate on its C code [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/inspect). The key is: when object has instance variables and *[some strange conditions]* are also met, it shows instance variables. Otherwise simply calls `to_s`. So putting `inspect` into `to_s` is a bad idea. I think you'd better go from other end: define your version of `puts`, say, `putsd`, which `inspect`'s its argutment before printing. That is the simplest way. Otherwise — modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend just using `p` to print instead of `puts`. `p` prints the result of `.inspect` on the object, which prints out the instance variables and their values, where `puts` prints out the result of `.to_s`, which does not print the instance variables.

Comment: Oh man I didn't event know about `p` thanks a lot Tom :)

Comment: That said, you can also overwrite `#inspect` to modify the output produced e.g. with `p`.